# Is there a simple way to get the most popular SoundCloud tracks at the moment?

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I need the "most popular" or "hottest tracks" from SoundCloud, but I don't find any way how to do that. I can get the newest tracks from

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?filter=streamable&limit=100&order=created_at
```

because the order type "hottest" doesn't exist anymore.
I want exactly the same songs that are listet at

```
https://soundcloud.com/explore
```

and then choose "Trending music". Is there any way to do that or not?

I thought about getting ~1000 songs, than sort out the most played and most favorited songs and only display them, but I think this is not the optimal solution.

Answer (score 3):

Why not try HTML Parsing ? You can get the entire page with a simple request, and then parse their (very nice and tidy) source code to get what you want.

There might be a better solution with their API, but this one seems very simple to me. Of course, your parsing might be broken if they decide to completely change this page layout.

On [this page](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/removing-hotness-param), they say you can do it with another API call.

Comment: Remember to only do this once each x minutes and store the data on your server. Otherwise Soundcloud might get a little upset with you visiting each time.

Comment: like yoeriboven said, therefor I need a server to cache the data. I also read the information on that page, but somehow ordering by "playback\\_count" or "favoriting\\_count" doesn't work (also 'playback_count' or 'favoritings_count' without the backslash won't work).

Comment: So, i tried out both (sort=favoritings_count and order=favoritings_count). None of them is working how it should, they're ordered by date and time and every song has "favoritings_count : 0".. super API!

Comment: I don't think a server is needed. You can just parse the data to a NSMutableArray, get everything you display from it, and refresh its content when you see fit.

yoeriboven raises an issue, though. If SoundCloud releases an API, they probably prefer that you use it rather than parsing their pages.

Comment: Your solution sounds nice, but maybe it would be nicer if I cache the "hottest" tracks on my own server, and my app loads the data from my server. So if SoundCloud changes the page layout, I don't need to update my app - just my server.